# Strtok returns the same word after being called using token = (NULL, "\n")

Tags: token, fgets, strtok

I am trying to tokenize a line read from a file but strtok() always returns the first word. Here is the code I have currently:

```
    fgets(line, 40, fp);
    token = strtok(line, " ");
    b[i].first_name = malloc(strlen(line));
    strcpy(b[i].first_name, line);

    token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    b[i].last_name = malloc(strlen(line));
    strcpy(b[i].last_name, line);
    
    b[i].number_order_registered = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *(b[i].number_order_registered) = i+1;

    printf("-%s, %s...%d!\n", b[i].last_name, b[i].first_name, *b[i].number_order_registered);
    fprintf(fOut, "-%s, %s...%d!\n", b[i].last_name, b[i].first_name, *b[i].number_order_registered);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the help on how to ask a question. A minimal complete running program that has the problem you cite is most likely to lead to someone willing to spend time to help you debug. One easily noticed thing here is that you're not allocating a character for the terminating null in your calls to `malloc`.  This probably doesn't affect strtok, but it will be your next problem.

Comment: Thank you I added them, also is free(b) sufficient to free all the malloc calls here or should I use free(b->first_name) etc.

Comment: As I said, you need a minimal, complete, running program, not a fragment. Also you have not made the change I was talking about.  The allocations need to be `malloc(strlen(line) + 1)` to allow space for the terminating null char. Without it, the `strcpy()` is writing the null to a byte you don't own, which means undefined behavior.